# How to check whether the Android application is open for the 1st time

Tags: android

I wanted to have a popup window when the user opens the application for the first time.

How can I check/get the number of times that the application has been opened?

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your application starts, during the `onCreate()` method, you can check to see if a SharedPreference exists.  If it does not, it is the first time this application is being launched.  Then create the SharedPreference.  So each subsequent time the application launches, the value will already be set and you'll know that it wasn't launched for the first time.

For more details on reading and setting SharedPreferences check out the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref