# showing a message dialog only once , when application is launched for the first time in android

Tags: android

I've developed an application in android and one of the important requirements is to show  a message dialog  for language support ONLY when the application is running for the first time ,then it will disappear each time the user is running the application again , I've tried to use shared preferences but it didn't work , is there is any other way to do that ??

Comment: the sharedpreference is a good choice. Why did not  work? Could post some code?

Comment: SharedPreferences should work just fine. Could you please paste the code for how you set and get the value from shared prefs?

Comment: Please check here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074713/how-to-check-whether-the-android-application-is-open-for-the-1st-time

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this function in onCreate handler:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (isFirstTime()) {
        // show dialog
    }
    ...
}


/***
 * Checks that application runs first time and write flag at SharedPreferences 
 * @return true if 1st time
 */
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return !ranBefore;
}
```

**Note**: it requires the permission to access a file on a storage: `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Need permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. See document https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Thanks, added to the answer

Comment: @K. Sopheak Did you even read the linked document? Nowhere is said that you need this permission. The reason is simple: you don't. Usually you save preference to your app's private directory which you can access anyway. I use SharedPreferences since from the beginning and never needed permission for this as far as I can remember. My current apps don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences would be the recommended way to go,  however you could also write the setting to the local sqllite database, or write it to a file that would be stored on the devices internal storage (sd card).

Answer (score -1):

You are returning "!ranBefore", surely you should be returning only "ranBefore".
Also you could be sure to always get the same shared preferences by using:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("yourSharedPreferanceName", 0);
```