# How do I change what screen I want my app to open on?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What I want is for my app to start on a Welcome Screen with some information on it but after the user moves past the Welcome Screen after the first time they open the app, I want the app to straight up open to the Home Screen.

E.g.

Open first time: Welcome Screen
User presses continue on Welcome Screen and goes to Home Screen
Open second time & every time after: Home Screen

Comment: Learn how to use `sharedPreferences`

Answer (score 1):

the SharedPreference is your best choice

in your Home Screen:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (isFirstTime()) {
        // show Welcome Screen
        startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, WelcomeScreen.class));
    }
    ...
}


/***
 * Checks that application runs first time and write flag at SharedPreferences 
 * @return true if 1st time
 */
private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return !ranBefore;
}
```

see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807054/3998402